# Word: how to find `_Refxxxxxxxxx` codes for manual cross-referencing?

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

When I use the Cross-reference dialog for figure and table cross-references, Word creates a new field with a reference number, e.g.:

`{ REF _Ref530727267 \h }`

How can I get the `_Refxxxxxxxxx` codes for the captions of my existing figures and tables? I want to insert the cross-reference fields manually, because the Cross-reference dialog is buggy and slow.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here:
https://wordaddins.com/support/cross-reference-fields-in-word/

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> opens the Bookmark dialog, and this will show all `_Refxxxxxxxxx` codes, if "Hidden bookmarks" is checked.

[image]

**Edit:**

It is slightly trickier than I first thought. The `_Refxxxxxxxxx` bookmarks are not created when you add a caption; they are generated by the Cross-reference dialog. Here are the steps to create a new bookmark:

1. Select the caption text you want in the cross-reference, e.g. `Figure 42`.
2. Open the Bookmark dialog with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.
3. Type a new bookmark name, e.g. `fig_dolphin`, and click "Add".

Not trivial I admit, but I really hate that cross-reference dialog.

Comment: Perfect! I needed this to reference figures in the appendixes. These shouldn't be included in the table of contents, so I edited the field codes and used a new identifier, but then these figures aren't listed in the Cross-reference dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're annoyed -like me- by the miniature Cross-reference dialog, you might want to have a look at my macro [InsertCrossReferencesComfortably](https://github.com/Traveler4/InsertCrossReferencesComfortably). 
It inserts cross references without fiddling with `_Refxxxxxxxxx` codes, in a more visual point-and-click-style.