# Unique ID for Fields and Cross References in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I am working with a collaborative Microsoft Word Document with Figures and Tables cross referenced throughout the document.  For instance, there are 75 figures linked with Captions.  We have cross referenced these captions to the Table of Contents and via cross references throughout the text.  Supplementally we created external spreadsheets itemizing these figures by row with "Fig XX Fig Title" (independent document; not linked by cross references in any way).  We have spend considerable time fleshing out these inventories of figures and tables, but now the figure numbers have shifted and names changed.  For future workflows, I want a way to determine a unique ID (field) in Word for these Figure and Table captions as they are not deleted, only changed.

I was able to find unique reference numbers for each cross reference field i.e. Figure 3-5 = {REF_Ref149214290\h}.  Is there also a unique reference number for the captions being referenced? I want to find a method to retain unique field reference numbers for each figure (caption) even when numbers and titles change from version to version.

[Word: how to find `_Refxxxxxxxxx` codes for manual cross-referencing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1377688/word-how-to-find-refxxxxxxxxx-codes-for-manual-cross-referencing)  -- **EDITED** *illustrates my query*

Comment: What you've found are hidden bookmarks. Word inserts them for any cross-reference or hyperliynk to something in the document other than to something that already has a bookmark created by the user.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesKenyon .  So is there any suggestion to track Captions (for figures and tables) when their titles change from version to version?  My confusion or research dead end is that I've determined how to find these Ref# to hidden bookmarks (thanks for that nugget!) but I can't find info on Ref# or identifiers for the object being referenced - i.e. the caption.  If I could find a way to access THAT in Word functionality or with VBA, then perhaps I could develop a workflow.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I know of no way to discover which number goes to where without actually going there. "titles change from version to version." I'm confused. Which titles?